# Task remains in running state after closing program

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I have this code in my WPF Application:

```
this.Closing += WindowOnClosing;
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

private void func()
{
    Task task = new Task.Factory.Start(() =>
    {
         // long running code...
    }), cts.Token);
    await task;
}

private void WindowOnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
     cts.Cancel();
}
```

But whenI close the window, the task remains in running state.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134310/how-to-cancel-a-task-in-await

Comment: You should cancel the closing in the `WindowOnClosing` handler and set a continuation for your task that closes the window on task cancellation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not use `StartNew` in this situation; use `Task.Run` instead. As I explain on my blog, [`StartNew` is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). (I'm assuming your actual code is using `StartNew`, since `new Task.Factory.Start` doesn't make any sense).

Second, in my [blog post on Delegate Tasks, I explain how the `CancellationToken` parameter of both `StartNew` and `Run` is misleading](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html).

[image: You keep using that cancellation token there. I do not think it means what you think it means.]

Specifically, the `CancellationToken` only cancels the *scheduling* of the delegate; it won't cancel the delegate itself. You have to respond to the cancellation in your own code:

```
private void func()
{
  var token = cts.Token;
  Task task = Task.Run(() =>
  {
    ...
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // Occasionally do this.
    ...
  });
  await task;
}
```

Comment: That only explains why he could never expect that the task is canceled once it start running. That did not explain, why he also can't expect the canceled state when the application finishes. There has to be a wait for the task

Answer (score -1):

I think after Cancel task you should wait for cancellation :

task.Wait();

also here is useful :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This would accomplish nothing other than to freeze the UI of his program for an extended period of time; it would in no way actually cancel the background task.

Comment: Its not cancel the task , its after sending the cancel flag and just wait to response the task, because the task maybe in work and after first time see the cancel flag it stop the task, after all its in the msdn ...

Comment: No, the problem with the OP's code is that he's not actually cancelling the task.  It's *desirable* that he isn't synchronously waiting on it.  Adding that only breaks the code *even more*.  It doesn't solve the actual problem, and it's actively harmful with or without adding the actual solution.