# Best-way for endless-task

Tags: c#, task

I have a task `outputTask`. The task reads the output of a `StreamReader` (with `StreamReader.ReadLineAsync()`),

It only works in this way:

```
var outputTask = plinkInstance.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync().ContinueWith(hasOutputReaded);

Action<Task<string>> hasOutputReaded = null;
hasOutputReaded = (previousTask) =>
{
    resetTimer.Invoke();
    _outputLines.Add(previousTask.Result);
    previousTask = plinkInstance.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
    previousTask.ContinueWith(hasOutputReaded);
};
```

It works yes, but is there a other way to make this better?

**Edit**: Now it looks this way

```
// ...
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => readUntilEnd(plinkInstance.StandardOutput, timer, cancel.Token), cancel.Token);
// ...
```

And the method

```
private static void readUntilEnd(StreamReader stream, System.Timers.Timer timer, CancellationToken canelToken)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[1];
    stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);
    int cooldown = 0;

    while (!canelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (buffer[0] != '\0')
        {
            readAChar(buffer[0]);
            buffer[0] = '\0';
            stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);

            timer.Stop();
            timer.Start();
            cooldown = 0;
         }
         else
         {
             if (cooldown < 100)
                 cooldown++;
         }

          if (cooldown > 0)
              Thread.Sleep(cooldown);
    }
}
```

Why I need the `CancellationToken`? I can also pass an bool-object, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're running your continuous task asynchronously, why not just make it an endless loop?

```
Task.Run(() =>
         {
            while (true)
            {
               var output = await READ_LINE_ASYNCHRONOUSLY();
               _outputLines.Add(output);
            }
         });
```

And if you need some way to break out of your loop (I'd assume you might), use `CancellationToken`, as described e.g. here:

[How to cancel a Task in await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134310/how-to-cancel-a-task-in-await)

EDIT: Here's the full code doing what you probably want to do:

```
Task.Run(() => ReadUntilEnd(streamReader, cancellationTokenSource.Token),
         cancellationTokenSource.Token);

//...

private static async Task ReadUntilEnd(StreamReader streamReader, 
                                       CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[1];
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await streamReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);
        readAChar(buffer[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The task is (at my first attempt) a local variable. So the GarbageCollector stops the loop (I guess). But here I have to write an additional cancellation.

Comment: No, GC won't stop your loop, as your task keeps referring itself, so it won't be viable for garbage collection. It will run for as long as your app (or thread, if you're doing something more complicated) is running.

I've also simplified my example - if for some reason you want to have a variable instead of providing the Task.Run() argument inline, you can do it. But it will still do nothing with respect to how and when the task is terminated.

Comment: Is the new way better? (Look at first post)

Comment: @user6537157 Yes in terms that it's a specific implementation of the generic one I've written above. No, because you're firing asynchronous methods (`ReadAsync`) without waiting for a result, but you're trying to use the result still (by accessing the `buffer` variable). Bedtime reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx , but the short version is: 1. make your `readUntilEnd` method `async Task` (instead of `void`) 2. add the `await` keyword before each call to `ReadAsync`

Comment: @user6537157 A significant problem with your code is that it will not work in a deterministic way - it might even work correctly some time, but at times it will miss some lines and read the same line twice, because of how your code progresses independently of the stream reading part.

Comment: Why it will miss lines or read the same twice? All tests are fine. Thanks for the hint with `await`-statement.

Comment: Sorry, not line, but character (if you won't use the async-await pattern, or some other way to synchronize your code). Imagine the following scenario - you're reading through a line, say you've read the 3rd character. Now you're running ReadAsync to read the 4th character; say the synchronizer decides to run this on a separate thread, but your thread takes priority and you loop back to the line reading from your `buffer` variable. Which still holds the 3rd character, so you happily read that. Also - if you use async-await, use `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) or better yet - scrap the whole sleeping bit altogether - that's what await will do for you implicitly when there's nothing new in the buffer.

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the method. Not any of `ReadAsync()` overloads take a `CancellationToken`, so I made it this way. What do you think? (Look at second answer)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static async Task readUntilEnd(StreamReader stream, System.Timers.Timer timer, CancellationToken canelToken)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[1];
    Task readTask = stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);
    int cooldown = 5;

    while (!canelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (readTask.IsCompleted)
        {
             readAChar(buffer[0]);

             buffer[0] = '\0';
             readTask = stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);

             timer.Stop();
             timer.Start();

             cooldown = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (cooldown < 100)
                cooldown++;
        }

        if (cooldown > 0)
            await Task.Delay(cooldown, canelToken);
    }

}
```