# How to wait for async timer callbacks

Tags: c#, timer, async-await

I'm using `System.Threading.Timer` to run some things that are `async`

It means my callbacks are `async void`.

```
private async void CallbackAsync(object state) {
    _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    await SomethingAsync();
    _timer.Change(TimeToNextCallback, Timeout.Inifinite);
}
```

With non async callbacks I have used code like this to shut down the timer safely.

```
using (var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false)) {
    if (_timer.Dispose(waitHandle))        {
        waitHandle.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

My understanding is that this will not work with async callbacks. The callback will return on the first `await` and the Timer is unaware of scheduled continations. I.e the code above might return before the continuations has completed (and the callback might try to change a disposed timer).

First, is my understanding correct?

Second, what is the correct way to wait for async callbacks to finish?

Comment: Standard [cancel task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134310/how-to-cancel-a-task-in-await) is seems like a possible route... Also I'd drop timer altogether and just `await Task.Delay(canelationToken)`...

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to achieve by using the timers?

Comment: Sorry, for late reply. The timer is old code that I am trying to update to support async callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct that your `Timer` will be unaware that your `CallbackAsync` function is still running and thus your call to `Dispose(WaitHandle)` will return and signal your `WaitHandle` immediately, at which point a call to `CallbackAsync` may make a call to `Timer.Change` after the `Timer` has been disposed.

There are a few red flags here:

1. You are using `async void`. This is almost always a bad idea because async functions *should* return a Task, otherwise there is nothing for a caller to await.
2. You are mixing `Thread` and `Task` paradigms.

Because `TimerCallback` does not support Tasks, the only way to make this work correctly while still using `Timer` would be to make your callback synchronous by dropping the `async/await` keywords and using `Task.Wait` to block until the `Task` returned by `SomethingAsync` is complete. As others have mentioned it would also be wise to add support for cancellation by creating a `CancellationToken` and passing it to `SomethingAsync`, that way when you call `Dispose` you will have the ability to cancel a running callback (this `CancellationToken` will need to be passed by `SomethingAsync` to any other async functions it calls and/or periodically checked for cancellation as `SomethingAsync` is executing).

**EDIT**: If you want to shift to a more natural `Task` based way of doing this see [Run async method regularly with specified interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval/30462282)

Comment: Was hoping for a simple change in existing code to support async callbacks. Seems like a rewrite to use Task.Delay instead is what is needed. Thanks for your input.

Comment: If you must use Timer than the simplest solution is to drop the async/await and call `.Wait()` on the task returned by the async code.