# Task parallel library file handles

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I am reading some files using parallel tasks. During this operation if i cancel the task the file handles are not closed. the tasks are successfully canceled. Looks like i need to do something more to close the file handles during a cancel but not able to figure out what i need to do. I was assuming that the task cancellation will dispose all objects but thats not the case.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancelling a task won't dispose of anything. I don't really know how you cancel or start your `Task`s since you haven't shown any code but the recommended way would be to call the `Cancel()` method of a task `CancellationTokenSource`. When your task is then doing what it is supposed to do it should check the tokens property `IsCancellationRequested`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783865/how-do-i-abort-cancel-tpl-tasks) explains the procedure pretty well.

The cleanup is totally up to you. The garbage collector will kill normal objects but you need to call `Dispose`, `Close` or the equivalent of any expensive object that you're using.

You have several options for this, calling `Dispose` manually, using a `using` block or implementing some sort of unit-of-work pattern.

Comment: I think a better way to test for cancellation is to call [`ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested), most of the time.