# Unable to close task started by Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, task

Hello I’m new to multithreading and tasks in C# .net from only help I have succeeded to start a new task taht can keep running inbackground using:

```
//if(tsk =NotRunning){
tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(TheMethod);
```

It is working fine by now but now when its started am unable to stop it now, I have been searching over [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321479.aspx) and found out few method that seems to be doing the job like `Dispose` buy they are not doing it, so I want to know two things:

- How can I check whether this task is already running? *(it’s an MVC project and the task is initiate with the controller call `…/Task/Start` so I don’t want to keep starting another instance of the task everytime this URL is accessed I want only one instance of it throughout the application running in the background)*
- Second how do I stop it than, I tried the following but didn’t work:

  ```
  public void TaskClose()
  {
      tsk.Dispose();
      var st = tsk.Status.ToString();
  }
  ```

I know there may be few answers regarding it available on internet but they mostly using Lambda expression and I am not very rehearsed with them so kindly provide answer in other way, I will even appreciate of you can point the right `method`  or `property` name that I can use to accomplish my result.

Thank you.

Comment: Suggest learning the lambda expression syntax and threading in isolation (both are reasonably advanced concepts), then when you're sure you've got them both nailed, combine the two ideas.

Comment: yeah i guess so i have already started that, but my other quesry still remian answered how do i check is the task is already running or not?

Comment: Ultimately, the answer to your original question is "you can't", which is why I suggested starting a little slower.

Comment: Also, you don't really want to have a background thread in an ASP.NET application. ASP.NET MVC and TPL (used in this way) just isn't a good mix. Just create a separate Windows service to handle any background stuff you need doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot stop TPL tasks. The proper way to handle this is to implement [cancellation tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4783890/29407).

Comment: Thankyou, but i may sound stupid here but is it not possible to do this without `Lambda Expression` I m new to it so cant really grasp whats happening, those examples are also using that and many others? :/

Comment: @Maven The task has an `IsCompleted` property.