# How to properly cancel Task.WhenAll and throw the first exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have multiple tasks that accept a cancellation token and call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` accordingly. These tasks will run concurrently using `Task.WhenAll`. I want all tasks to be cancelled when any tasks throw an exception. I achieved this using `Select` and `ContinueWith`:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

try
{
    var tasks = new Task[] { DoSomethingAsync(cts.Token), ... } // multiple tasks here
        .Select(task => task.ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
            }
        }));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (SpecificException)
{
    // Why is this block never reached?
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, it seems to have some issues. It appears the exception will be caught internally, code after `WhenAll` is always reached. I don't want the code after `WhenAll` to be reached when an exception has occurred, I'd rather have the exception to be thrown so I can catch it manually on another level of the call stack. What's the best way to achieve this? If possible I'd like the call stack to remain intact. If multiple exceptions occur it would be best if only the first exception is rethrown, no `AggregateException`.

---

On a related note, I tried passing the cancellation token to `ContinueWith` like so: `task.ContinueWith(lambda, cts.Token)`. However, when an exception in any task occurs, this will eventually throw a `TaskCanceledException` instead of the exception I'm interested in. I figured I should pass the cancellation token to `ContinueWith` because this would cancel `ContinueWith` itself, which I don't think is what I want.

Comment: @Servy The difference between this question and the "duplicate" is that this is about `Task.WhenAll` and using try-catch outside the task. The other question is about joining multiple `ContinueWith` and checking task.Exception explicitly.

Comment: The difference isn't relevant.  `WhenAll` is just going to attach its own continuation using `ContinueWIth`, and it's going to be checking the `Exception` value when determining whether it should fault itself or not, leaving you with exactly the same issue.  That some of it is happening behind the scenes of `WhenAll` isn't meaningfully different to explaining the problem or correcting it.

Comment: @Servy I do not understand how your explanation or the other thread answer my question on how to have the exception to be thrown like it normally would, allowing me to handle the exception outside TPL on another level of the call stack.

Comment: You don't add your second continuation to the first continuation, rather you have both continuations added to the original `Task`.

Comment: @Servy There is no second continuation. Each task in the array gets one single continuation added. If there are 100 tasks in the array it results in 100 tasks each with their own continuation that handles the cancellation.

Comment: Yes, there is a second continuation for each task, which I've already told you before.  That you're calling a method that's adding the continuation instead of adding it explicitly doesn't mean you're not adding a second continuation.

Comment: @Servy Okay, now that I understand I'm dealing with chained continuations, I can see how the other thread answers my question. However, I would not have known `WhenAll` implicitly attaches its own continuation if I hadn't asked this question, the other thread does not touch this subject. So I do not see how my question is a duplicate.

Comment: What else do you expect `WhenAll` to do?  And regardless you have a collection of tasks, of which none of them are faulted, and you know none of them are faulted, so why would you expect `WhenAll` to fault when you pass that collection in?

Comment: What do I expect? I don't know. I have zero understanding of TPL. Thanks to `async`/`await`, I never had to use `ContinueWith` until now. Only because of your last comment I now understand that adding a continuation to a faulted task results in a task that will not fault.

Comment: Then you didn't read the duplicate, because it would have told you as much.  It's literally how the answer opens.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ContinueWith`. The correct answer is to introduce another "higher-level" `async` method instead of attaching a continuation to each task:

```
private async Task DoSomethingWithCancel(CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    try
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        throw;
    }
}
```

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    var tasks = new Task[] { DoSomethingWithCancel(cts), ... };
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (SpecificException)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Stephen's answer, usage: `await someTask.CancelOnError(cts)`

It requires two extension methods to handle both Task and Task`T:

```
public static async Task CancelOnError(this Task task, CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    try
    {
        await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch
    {
        cts.Cancel();

        throw;
    }
}

public static async Task<TTaskResult> CancelOnError<TTaskResult>(this Task<TTaskResult> task, CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    await ((Task)task).CancelOnError(cts);

    return task.Result;
}
```

Comments are welcome, give it a try!