# ThrowIfCancellationRequested doesn't seem to throw any exceptions

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task, cancellationtokensource

I have the following code :

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
         cts.Cancel();
     Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit");
});

 Parallel.ForEach(list, po, (algo) =>
 {
      algo.Compute(); // this compute lasts 1 minute  
      Console.WriteLine("this job is finished");       
      po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
 });
```

The `list` contains few elements.
All the `Compute` methods have already been started when I press 'c'.

When I press 'c', no exception is thrown. Each `Compute` methods continues its execution until its normal end.

I would like to stop/kill all the remain `Compute` methods when I press 'c'.

Comment: I think you need to handle the cancelation in the `Unit-Of-Work` method manually` Once the thread is started, it is on it`s own. You need to throw this from within the thread AFAIK.

Comment: Yep, you have to pass the cancellation token to `algo.Compute()` and check it within that method's loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I abort/cancel TPL Tasks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783865/how-do-i-abort-cancel-tpl-tasks)

Comment: Just by placing the magic `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` line somewhere in the source code does not make anything happen. That line needs to be executed as well.

Answer (score 3):

Cancellation doesn't work like that. It's not like calling `Thread.Abort()` to terminate thread immediately.

For each element in a sequence your code does:

1. Calls `Compute()` method
2. Waits until its completion
3. Writes to console about finish
4. Checks if cancellation was requested and throw the `OperationCanceledException` if it was.

In order to cancel some task you need to pass the `CancellationToken` to the called method.
Perhaps, it's worth organizing your long running computations as a cycle and check if cancellation were requested at each step in order to stop it ASAP.

For example, in your `Compute()` method you could perform check like this:

```
private void Compute(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (true)
    {
       ComputeNextStep();
       ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

Comment: I`ll add to this that the point of the `CancellationToken` is to be the connecting thread (pun intended) between the process which seeded the new thread and the thread itself. If the seeding process could cancel the thread, there would be no need for a cancelation token, would there? :) So the `CancellationToken` is for signalling. You need to handle the signal.

Comment: Oh and one more thing... This is also a good design, since before being cancled, your code might want to dispose of some objects or handles. Just "killing" the thread from outside can create memory / resource issues. Better to let the thread handle the cancelation.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the cancellation with `po.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` and use [`ParallelLoopState.Stop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to stop `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
void Compute(CancellationToken token, ParallelLoopState loopState)
{
    bool more = true;
    while (more)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // stop Parallel.ForEach ASAP
            loopState.Stop();
            return;
        }
        // do the calc step
    }
}

// ... 

CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
        cts.Cancel();
    Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit");
});

Parallel.ForEach(list, po, (algo, loopState) =>
{
    algo.Compute(po.CancellationToken, loopState); // this compute lasts 1 minute  
    Console.WriteLine("this job is finished");
});
// observe the cancellation again and throw after Parallel.ForEach
po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```