# Call method from caller class and avoid circular dependency

Tags: c#, class, design-patterns, .net-assembly, circular-dependency

I have a windows forms application contains of 3 projects in 1 solution.

`Hall.Client` <-- Winforms

`Hall.Admin` <-- Winforms

`Hall.Processor` <-- Class Library

`Hall.Client` and `Hall.Admin` need `Hall.Processor` as a reference. `Hall.Processor` can't add reference to both `Hall.Client` and `Hall.Admin` because of circular dependency.
All I need is to get instance of each caller class in `Hall.Processor`

In `Hall.Client` I have a class called Canopy

```
public class Canopy : System.Windows.Form
{
    public void SetProcessName(string name)
    {
        this.txtProcessName.Text = name;
    }
}
```

In `Hall.Admin` I have a class called Roof

```
public class Roof : System.Windows.Form
{
    public void SetProcessName(string name)
    {
        this.txtProcessName.Text = name;
    }
}
```

I have a method in `Hall.Processor` inside the Builder class

```
public class Builder
{
    Form form;
    public Builder(Form form)
    {
        //Here the main problem.
        //if the caller class is Hall.Admin.Roof then this.form should be Hall.Admin.Roof
        //if the caller class is Hall.Client.Canopy then this.form should be Hall.Client.Canopy
    }
    public void SetProcessName()
    {
        //How to call method in caller class directly from this class
        //if(Admin.Roof) then form.SetProcessName("something about admin");
        //if(Client.Canopy) then form.SetProcessName("something about client");
    }
}
```

I need suggestion how to solve my problem. Is there any design pattern related to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decouple classes from each other through the use of interfaces. You can have all interfaces declared inside the `Processor` library, or better yet in a separate library, shared between `Client`, `Admin` and `Processor` projects. Then you could do the checks like `form is IRoof` or `form is ICanopy`.

Note however, in this case nothing would prevent `Admin` from implementing `ICanopy` or `Client` from doing `IRoof`. If this is really an issue, make the interfaces `internal`, and control their visibility to other assemblies via `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Assembly")]` (see [**"Friend Assemblies"**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx)).

Further, search the web for **"Dependency Injection"**.

Comment: I am still confusing of your explanation. There are tons of examples on the webs and none of them match my need.

Comment: @derodevil, what is exactly confusing? Are you familiar with [interfaces in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22549046/1768303)?

Comment: Yes I am. What I'm thinking is Factory Pattern and not DI. That's what I'm confusing.

Comment: You factory can be as simple as `Type.GetType`/`Activator.CreateInstance`. This is not "either Factory or DI":  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163739.aspx