# Task Cancellation Request

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

Is `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` in Asynchronous Tasks leaks memory? Is there any  way to stop a running task immediately which don't leaks memory? I want to use some process immediately and want to free memory.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14738990/1287352 for killing a task with thread.Abort()

Comment: Why do you think `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` leaks memory? Show us your code

Comment: This can't be done. NET does not have a way to safely kill a thread. Abort() is unusable.