# Why is the task is not cancelled when I call CancellationTokenSource's Cancel method in async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I created a small wrapper around `CancellationToken` and `CancellationTokenSource`. The problem I have is that the `CancelAsync` method of `CancellationHelper` doesn't work as expected.

I'm experiencing the problem with the `ItShouldThrowAExceptionButStallsInstead` method. To cancel the running task, it calls `await coordinator.CancelAsync();`, but the task is not cancelled actually and doesn't throw an exception on `task.Wait`

`ItWorksWellAndThrowsException` seems to be working well and it uses `coordinator.Cancel`, which is not an async method at all.

The question why is the task is not cancelled when I call `CancellationTokenSource`'s Cancel method in async method?

Don't let the `waitHandle` confuse you, it's only for not letting the task finish early.

Let the code speak for itself:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestCancellation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ItWorksWellAndThrowsException();
            //ItShouldThrowAExceptionButStallsInstead();
        }

        private static void ItShouldThrowAExceptionButStallsInstead()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var coordinator = new CancellationHelper();
                var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

                var task = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    waitHandle.WaitOne();

                    //this works well though - it throws
                    //coordinator.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                }, coordinator.Token);

                await coordinator.CancelAsync();
                //waitHandle.Set(); -- with or without this it will throw
                task.Wait();
            }).Wait();
        }

        private static void ItWorksWellAndThrowsException()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var coordinator = new CancellationHelper();
                var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);

                var task = Task.Run(() => { waitHandle.WaitOne(); }, coordinator.Token);

                coordinator.Cancel();
                task.Wait();
            }).Wait();
        }
    }

    public class CancellationHelper
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
        private readonly List<Task> tasksToAwait;

        public CancellationHelper()
        {
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            tasksToAwait = new List<Task>();
        }

        public CancellationToken Token
        {
            get { return cancellationTokenSource.Token; }
        }

        public void AwaitOnCancellation(Task task)
        {
            if (task == null) return;

            tasksToAwait.Add(task);
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            tasksToAwait.Clear();
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        public void ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        public void Cancel()
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

            Task.WaitAll(tasksToAwait.ToArray());
        }

        public async Task CancelAsync()
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(tasksToAwait.ToArray());
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                ex.Handle(p => p is OperationCanceledException);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `CancellationHelper.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`?

Comment: I believe there's a misunderstanding of how canellation token works... ie for `Task.Run` the token is only relevant during build up of the task, when running, you have to check the token yourself ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I understand what you're saying, but if the task completes and at some point during execution ```CancellationTokenSource.Cancel``` is called, then its ```task.Result``` should be ```TaskStatus.Canceled``` shouldn't it?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair If I understand it correctly once a task starts executing the ```task.Status``` won't be ```TaskStatus.Canceled``` even if ```Cancel``` is called and I have to check ```CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested```

Comment: @boli There might be a chance for `TaskStatus.Faulted` if you incorporate `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I abort/cancel TPL Tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783865/how-do-i-abort-cancel-tpl-tasks)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cancellation in .NET is cooperative.

That means that the one holding the `CancellationTokenSource` signals cancellation and the one holding the `CancellationToken` needs to check whether cancellation was signaled (either by polling the `CancellationToken` or by registering a delegate to run when it is signaled).

In your `Task.Run` you use the `CancellationToken` as a parameter, but you don't check it inside the task itself so the task will only be cancelled if the token was signaled before the task had to a chance to start.

To cancel the task while it's running you need to check the `CancellationToken`:

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}, token);
```

---

In your case you block on a `ManualResetEvent` so you wouldn't be able to check the `CancellationToken`. You can register a delegate to the `CancellationToken` that frees up the reset event:

```
token.Register(() => waitHandle.Set())
```

Comment: var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}, token); looks good. But where to catch the exception.