# Cancelling a task from a list of tasks

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, service, task-parallel-library

I have a requirement to poll database and create parquet file for each table. This tasks are to run in parallel with some configurable limit on the number of threads to be created.
Once the threads are added and the tasks starts to run I need to set a timer so that if any query take more than some specified time can cancel the task and close that thread. If anymore task is there in the collection then the next thread will be called.
I am using `CancellationTokenSource` but it is not working as expected.

```cs
public async static Task CreateExtractionAndUpload(ConfigurationDetails config)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(10000);
    
    List<Task> getData = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var query in config.Root.Queries)
    {
        getData.Add(Task.Run(() => DoExtractionFromQueries(query, dbManager, cts.Token)));
    }

     await Task.WhenAll(getData);
}

private async static void DoExtractionFromQueries(ExtractionQueries query, DBManager dBManager, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    try
    {
        while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            var dataTable = dBManager.GetDataTable(query.Query, System.Data.CommandType.Text);
            //ParaquetFileHandler.GenerateParquetFile(dataTable);
        }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("Query taking longer than expected time!", ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error("Exception in running query!", ex);
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong and how to rectify it?
How can I limit the number of threads?
I can limit the threads in `Parallel.Foreach` but can I cancel a task after timeout?

Comment: The cancellation token is only checked here `cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested` so because `Thread.Sleep(); var dataTable = dBManager.GetDataTable` will block for a number of seconds the token will not be checked again until after these 2 lines have executed.

Comment: the code looks odd. You set the task to be canceled after 10s, but the first thing you do is sleep for 20s. So each task should call the database exactly once. And cancelling is cooperative, i.e. `GetDataTable` will always run to completion.

Comment: Related: [Why is the task is not cancelled when I call CancellationTokenSource's Cancel method in async method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975590/why-is-the-task-is-not-cancelled-when-i-call-cancellationtokensources-cancel-me)

Comment: @Ben Yes thats what is happening. I want to exit that thread. How can I exit it.

Comment: @JonasH So in may actual scenario I want to cancel the thread if it takes time to execute the query. To replicate the issue I put this sleep thinking it will come out. But it is not working. What do I do to fix this.

Comment: Does your `dbManager` have async version of the `GetDataTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using CancellationTokenSource but it is not working as expected.

Cancellation in .NET is cooperative. So the code must *check* whether it is canceled. If it doesn't check, it's not canceled.

In this case, you'll probably need to modify `dBManager.GetDataTable` to make it cancel-aware: add a `CancellationToken` parameter to that method, and pass it to any long-running methods that it calls.

Answer (score -2):

One way to achieve this if you cannot make GetDataTable async (and to accept a cancellation token) is to configure your db connection's timeout and then you could:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(
    source: config.Root.Queries,
    parallelOptions: new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = NUMBER },
    body: (query) => DoExtractionFromQueries(query, dBManager)
```

Please note that if you go the recommended way of making GetDataTable async then you move from *parallelism* to *concurrency*. There is no trivial way to set a "max level of concurrency" when working with Tasks. You will need to do a search or two to find an alternative to Task.WhenAll which allows setting a limit to number of concurrent tasks.

Comment: While I tend to agree on Parallel.Foreach instead of tasks, this answer does not address core of the issue, i.e. aborting if it takes longer than some timeout.

Comment: @JonasH You're 100% correct, but Stephen-Cleary's answer doesn't tackle the "configurable limit on the number of threads to be created" aspect :) I've rewritten the answer to address the timeout and added a note about parallelism/concurrency.