# How to wait for a function execution for specific duration

Tags: c#, wait, freeze

My C# application stops responding for a long time, as I break the Debug it stops on a function.

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    xmldiff.Compare(item, secondary, output);
    ...
}
```

I guess the running time of this function is long or it hangs. Anyway, I want to wait for a certain time (e.g. 5 seconds) for the execution of this function, and if it exceeds this time, I skip it and go to the next item in the loop. How can I do it? I found some similar question but they are mostly for processes or asynchronous methods.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: It really depends on internal code of the method `Compare()` itself. There is no magic code that we can insert that will just suspend/abort anything like that

Comment: If you are using .net version 4.0 and above i suggest you to look into TPL/ async...await. For long running process that shouldn't block/Hang the UI. You need to push the process to a background thread preferably in threadpool.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it seems the current answer works for my case.

Comment: Works does not make it good, expect worse problems in the future caused by this "patch". (I can't call  it a fix because it's not)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the brutal way: spin up a thread to do the work, join it with timeout, then abort it, if the join didn't work.

Example:

```
var worker = new Thread( () => { xmlDiff.Compare(item, secondary, output); } );
worker.Start();
if (!worker.Join( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 1 ) ))
    worker.Abort();
```

But be warned - aborting threads is not considered nice and can make your app unstable. If at all possible try to modify `Compare` to accept a `CancellationToken` to cancel the comparison.

Comment: Why down-vote? Is there any other non-cooperative method to cancel a method besides aborting the thread it runs in?

Comment: Thanks it seems working, I will accept it when I got sure

Comment: Aborting a thread can lead to corruption in the `AppDomain`. It should only ever be done when forceably shutting down an app. It is terrible to suggest this as a normal way to code.

Comment: If it is the only solution to the problem at hand, it might be worth the risk. We don't know whether it is possible for him to move the processing in another process for example. BTW - when shutting down an app, it is better to kill the process, as that's guaranteed to work while `Thread.Abort` will only abort threads that are currently executing managed code. If the thread hangs in an unmanaged lib, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid directly using threads and use Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (NuGet "Rx-Main") to abstract away the management of the threads.

I don't know the exact signature of `xmldiff.Compare(item, secondary, output)` but if I assume it produces an integer then I could do this with Rx:

```
var query =
    from item in list.ToObservable()
    from result in
        Observable
            .Start(() => xmldiff.Compare(item, secondary, output))
            .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0), Observable.Return(-1))
    select new { item, result };

var subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            /* do something with `x.item` and/or `x.result` */
        });
```

This automatically iterates through each `item` and starts a background computation of `xmldiff.Compare`, but only allows each computation to take as much as `5.0` seconds before returning a default value of `-1`.

The `subscription` variable is an `IDisposable`, so if you want to abort the entire `query` before it completes just call `.Dispose()`.

Answer (score 0):

> I skip it and go to the next item in the loop

By "skip it", do you mean "leave it there" or "cancel it"? The two scenarios are quite different. But for both two I suggest you use `Task`.

```
//generate 10 example tasks
var tasks = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 10)
    .Select(n => new Task(() => DoSomething(n)))
    .ToList();

var maxExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    if (task.Wait(maxExecutionTime))
    {
        //the task is finished in time
    }
    else
    {
        // the task is over time
        // just leave it there
        // the loop continues
        // if you want to cancel it, see 
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783865/how-do-i-abort-cancel-tpl-tasks
    }
}
```

One thing to improve is "do you really need to run your tasks one by one?" If they are independent you can run them in parallel.