# How to cancel running task using different request in c#?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I have started a task on `Start Task` button click and want to cancel that task > using `Cancel Task` button. But I am not able to find & cancel running task.

```
public ActionResult StartTask()
{
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken ct = tokenSource.Token;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
          // do some work...
        }, tokenSource.Token);

        return view();
}

public ActionResult CancelTask()
{
   //Here i want to cancel above task.
   return view();
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try passing the CancellationToken as the second parameter to Task.Factory.StartNew

```
CancellationToken ct = tokenSource.Token;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
            // do some work...

            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // another thread decided to cancel
                Console.WriteLine("task canceled");
                break;
            }
    }, ct);
```

and issue tokenSource.Cancel() to cancel

Note: A similar thread can be found here
[How do I abort/cancel TPL Tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783865/how-do-i-abort-cancel-tpl-tasks)