# Stop foreach in asynchronous task on key press passing a cancellation token

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, loops, async-await

I'm running a `foreach` and I would like to cancel its execution on a key press.

While I succeeded doing it integrating a single if (keypress) within the loop, now I'm trying to achieve the same using a `CancellationToken` while the task for listening for a key stroke is running.

```
var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = ts.Token;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (var station in stations)
        {
            /*if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                break;
            }*/
            Console.WriteLine(station.name + " ");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
                    // another thread decided to cancel
                    Console.WriteLine("task canceled");
            break;
        }
    }
}, ct);
ts.Cancel();
Console.ReadLine();
```

I came from this answer [How do I abort/cancel TPL Tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783865/how-do-i-abort-cancel-tpl-tasks) which helped me a lot.
However, while it works without the `foreach`, right now the `foreach` has to end before the task is cancelled.
Obviously, it looks like the iteration has to end before proceeding to the next step and what I don't understand is how I can make the `foreach` stop.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested?view=net-5.0

Comment: So you want to stop the `foreach` loop in a non-cooperative fashion? I don't think that the `CancellationToken` can help you with that. Cancellation in .NET [is cooperative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).

Comment: I think your are trying to achieve a event driven approach. You even tried to create a even loop inside your task. But Event Loops should be the top structure in an event driven application and all the other stuff should be put inside a loop asynchronously (like a Task). Try move your while loop out of your Task... The loop should be running in foreground to detect your events and the task in background

Answer (score 3):

Cancellation is co-operative.

You need to check inside the `foreach()` and at any other appropriate point in your routines, to see if cancellation has been requested.

If it has, then you could prematurely exit out of the `foreach()`, (if your logic allows it), while ensuring that you clean up any resources and complete any actions that need to be completed.

Also, I suggest, instead of `Thread.Sleep()`, use `await Task.Delay(100);`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though it's as simple as repeating your `if`:

```
var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = ts.Token;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (var station in stations)
        {
            /*if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                break;
            }*/
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // another thread decided to cancel
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(station.name + " ");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
                    // another thread decided to cancel
                    Console.WriteLine("task canceled");
            break;
        }
    }
}, ct);
ts.Cancel();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented before, I think you're trying to achieve something like this:

```
    public class Program
{
    static ConcurrentQueue<int> queue = new(); // >= .NET 5 / C# 9 only

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var rand = new Random();
        Task activeTask = null;

        while (true)
        {
            var keyPressed = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            if (keyPressed == ConsoleKey.Q)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                    queue.Enqueue(rand.Next(0, 1000));

                Console.WriteLine("Random elements enqueued");
            }

            if (keyPressed == ConsoleKey.D)
            {
                if(activeTask == null)
                {
                    ts.Dispose();
                    ts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                    CancellationToken ct = ts.Token;
                    activeTask = BackgroundLoopAction(ct);
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Background loop task already running");
            }

            if (keyPressed == ConsoleKey.X)
            {
                ts.Cancel();
                activeTask = null;
            }
                

            if (keyPressed == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                break;
        }
    }

    private static Task BackgroundLoopAction(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                queue.TryDequeue(out int q);
                Console.WriteLine($"Dequeued element: {q}");
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(ct.IsCancellationRequested ? "Task canceled by user event" : "Task completed");
        }, ct);
    }
}
```

[image: App Output]