# Windows 8 app: handling menu calling long time http request

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, threadpool

In my App, I have **a menu which loads a page making a http request to retrieve data**.
This http request usually last ~500ms or more.

Right now, I use an async method which nicely shows a progressRing during the loading.

**Problem starts when I start to click on several menu input in a row (like 5 items in 1 second)
=> Pages loads one after the other.**

I would like to kill the current process and launch the new process everytime the user select a new menu input.

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359910/is-it-possible-to-abort-a-task-like-aborting-a-thread-thread-abort-method) and [here](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2012/03/17/No-Threads-for-you-in-metro-style-apps.aspx) that Thread.Abort is not a good practice. (was my first idea)
I've also found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783865/how-do-i-abort-cancel-tpl-tasks) I might use a task. But I can't set up correctly the cancelation event (it's not like in the exemple, where they just loop and decide to raise the cancelation event, i have a http request going on)

**Is there any good practice out there?**

Thx a lot !

Comment: pass cancellation token into http request and when you want cancel the request just Cancel() method of cancellationtokensource.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155759.aspx

Comment: Thx loop and Christian Fischer! Problem is: in my case i'm using a DLL I can't modify, which handle the http request process. And none of the implemented method allow me to use a cancellationtokensource.
I realize I didn't mention it before, my bad.