# How to abort a HttpWebRequest (from another thread)?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I like to abort HttpWebRequest when necessary from another thread. Is it right way to do it ?

```
    public void Abort()
    {
        if (request != null)
        {
            try { request.ReadWriteTimeout = 0; } catch { }
            try { request.Timeout = 0; } catch { }
            try { request.Abort(); } catch { }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will save you some effort to put everything inside one try/catch. Also look at this: [Is it possible to abort a Task like aborting a Thread (Thread.Abort method)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359910/is-it-possible-to-abort-a-task-like-aborting-a-thread-thread-abort-method)

```
public void Abort()
{
    if (request != null)
    {
        try 
        { 
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 0; } catch { }
            request.Timeout = 0;
            request.Abort(); 
        } catch {//Some error}
    }
}
```