# How can I set a thread or task to automatically abort/cancel after a given time in dotnet core in docker?

Tags: c#, linux

I have a specific situation in my dotnet core code that requires me to be able to abort/cancel a thread running third party code that frequently gets stuck in its execution.

I am unable to use the recommended practice of cancellation tokens since the third party code is the offending party.

The offending code is from the ssh.net project and the bug I am trying to avoid/solve is the following one:
https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/355

The following (excellent) suggestion would help me but it is made by using the kernel32 dll and I have to make the code work under docker in a Linux environment:
[Is it possible to abort a Task like aborting a Thread (Thread.Abort method)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359910/is-it-possible-to-abort-a-task-like-aborting-a-thread-thread-abort-method/55709530#55709530)

I have looked at the libc specifications in Linux but I have a hard time figuring out what would be the correct implementation on that platform.

```
ThreadHelper.RunWithAbort(() => {
    Client?.Disconnect();
    Client?.Dispose();
}, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

The code should be able to terminate the third party code if it freezes and not affect the rest of the application or the system itself.