# Cancellation Token doesen't work in Parallel.Foreach in c#

Tags: c#, task, parallel.foreach

I have a problem with cancellation token that doesn't work. I created a simple code example of my actual project. This is my scenario:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var taskCheker = new TaskChecker();
        taskCheker.Test();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
public class TaskChecker
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
        Parallel.ForEach(list, (item) =>
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cancellationToken.CancelAfter(1000);
            try
            {
                var task = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"item: {item} with thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} started");
                    LongTask();
                    Console.WriteLine($"item: {item} with thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} finished");
                }, cancellationToken.Token);
                Task.WaitAll(new[] { task });
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TaskCanceledException runned");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Exception runned");
            }

        });
        Console.WriteLine("Parallel finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public void LongTask()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

I have a `Parallel.Foreach` that calls inner `Task` for each item. Inner `Task` has a cancellation token with 1 second. Inner `Task` call a `LongTask` method that it takes 2 seconds, and I expect that all of my inner tasks throw timeout. But all of them call and after 2 seconds will complete. So I don't know why my cancellation token doesn't work.

Thank you so much to your help

Comment: This article explains quite well what the `CancellationToken` does in this case: [A Tour of Task, Part 9: Delegate Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html)

Comment: The following question might be relevant to what you are trying to achieve: [How to abort a Task like aborting a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359910/how-to-abort-a-task-like-aborting-a-thread-thread-abort-method) If you find it interesting, make sure to read also this: [What's wrong with using Thread.Abort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort)

Answer (score 2):

In `Task.Run` if the `IsCancellationRequested` is set to true before the task is actually running then it won't run.

But if the task already running before the `IsCancellationRequested` is true then it's your responsibility to call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` in your task.

This is from MSDN:

> Cancellation is cooperative and is not forced on the listener. The listener determines how to gracefully terminate in response to a cancellation request.

[MSDN Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)

Comment: What I have to do for timeout, I don't want to call `IsCancellationRequested ` manualy

Comment: @AmirhosseinYari as he said, is impossible to do what you want (stop task without verify IsCancellationRequested  in task code). This because cancellation token is a graceful attempt to terminate one task. Graceful not forced. If you want to stop a task (no matter what he does) you should use a `Kill()`

Comment: @AmirhosseinYari `Task.Wait` takes a `TimeSpan` your can set a timeout for each task.

Comment: Task.Wait doesn't wok too!. Thank you @HMZ,@Giovanni Esposito, I didn't know about graceful behavior

Comment: But I couldn't find a way to do that yet.