# Task cancellation in C# not working as expected - need to clear old tasks before starting new ones

Tags: c#, asynchronous, websocket, async-await, cancellation-token

I have a C# application where I manage multiple IP cameras. Each camera runs a task that performs a series of operations like starting a socket, streaming data, and running an object detection model. I manage these tasks using a dictionary that holds the camera index and its corresponding CancellationTokenSource.

My issue is that when I change the settings for a camera, I want to `first` cancel the existing task for that camera `and then` start a new one. However, it seems like the new task starts before the old one finishes clearing, and this creates problems.

Here's the sample code:

### Main method that starts the task for a camera:

```
internal static Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, CancellationTokenSource>> tokenSources = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, CancellationTokenSource>>();

private async Task IPCameraMethod()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxUrl.Text) ||
        !int.TryParse(SourceComboBox.Name.Replace("comboBox", ""), out int cameraIndex) ||
        comboBoxSavedCameras.SelectedIndex < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    string url = textBoxUrl.Text;
    int selectedItemIndex = comboBoxSavedCameras.SelectedIndex;

    if (tokenSources.TryGetValue(cameraIndex, out var tuple))
    {
        if (selectedItemIndex != tuple.Item1)
        {
            tuple.Item2.Cancel();
            tuple.Item2.Dispose();
            tokenSources.Remove(cameraIndex);
        }
    }

    var newCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    tokenSources[cameraIndex] = Tuple.Create(selectedItemIndex, newCts);

    Debug.WriteLine("CREATING NEW TASK");
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        Camera.IPCameraService.Main(SourceImageControl, selectedItemIndex, newCts.Token, url),
        newCts.Token,
        TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
        TaskScheduler.Default
    );
}
```

### Task method being called

```
public async Task Main(System.Windows.Controls.Image imageControl, int cameraIndex, CancellationToken token, string cameraUrl)
{
    CameraURLs[cameraIndex] = cameraUrl;

    await StartSocket(cameraIndex);
    await StartStream(cameraIndex, cameraUrl);

    EventHandler(cameraUrl, cameraIndex);
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var frame = await RunYolo(cameraIndex);
        if (frame != null)
            await UpdateDisplay(frame, imageControl);
    }

    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Clearing Websocket!");
        var ws = CameraWebsockets[cameraIndex];
        if (ws != null && ws.State == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Cancellation requested", CancellationToken.None);
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Issue:
The output I see is:

```
CREATING NEW TASK
Clearing Websocket!
```

I would expect to see "Clearing Websocket!" before "CREATING NEW TASK". How can I enforce this order?

Attempts:

I tried to wait for the task to complete using await but I'm still experiencing the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `IPCameraMethod` needs to track tasks which it has invoked (static list of tasks?), and when it is invoked again, it should wait until tasks state is `RanToCompletion` or any other

Comment: You should read on what "Cancel" means - TLDR can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4359927/477420

Comment: Side note: not passing cancellation token to inner async methods is quite strange when you really want speedy cancellation.

Comment: Hello @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for your response, could you kindly explain what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems. First, your code is using `Task.Factory.StartNew` for asynchronous code, which is wrong ~99.9% of the time. I am honestly surprised at how often it's used, since it's just wrong; I see it quite often. The correct replacement is `Task.Run`.

Second, your code cancels the CTS but then it doesn't `await` the old task before starting the next one. Your code should save the task in its data structure and then `await` it before starting the next one.

Combining both of these:

```
static Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, CancellationTokenSource, Task>> tokenSources = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, CancellationTokenSource, Task>>();

private async Task IPCameraMethod()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxUrl.Text) ||
        !int.TryParse(SourceComboBox.Name.Replace("comboBox", ""), out int cameraIndex) ||
        comboBoxSavedCameras.SelectedIndex < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    string url = textBoxUrl.Text;
    int selectedItemIndex = comboBoxSavedCameras.SelectedIndex;

    if (tokenSources.TryGetValue(cameraIndex, out var tuple))
    {
        if (selectedItemIndex != tuple.Item1)
        {
            tuple.Item2.Cancel();
            tuple.Item2.Dispose();
            await tuple.Item3;
            tokenSources.Remove(cameraIndex);
        }
    }

    var newCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    tokenSources[cameraIndex] = Tuple.Create(selectedItemIndex, newCts, (Task)null);

    Debug.WriteLine("CREATING NEW TASK");
    tokenSources[cameraIndex].Item3 = Task.Run(() =>
        Camera.IPCameraService.Main(SourceImageControl, selectedItemIndex, newCts.Token, url)
    );
}
```