# Cancel async CPU calculations as new ones are requested

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an app that needs to do some rather expensive CPU-bound work when a value is changed in the UI.

In order to not hang the UI, the control's `onchange` event calls an `async` method to do the work in the background. At the moment, I have something like this:

```
namespace Example
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public double Result { get; set; } = 0;
        public async Task UpdateAsync(double value)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => Process(value));
        }
        private double Process(double value)
        {
            // Simulate some heavy processing
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return value * 2;
        }
    }
}
```

This works as expected, the UI stays reactive, but rapid changes to the value lead to multiple-seconds lag until the `Result` value settles on the final result.

I have tried to experiment with `CancellationToken` to cancel the previous task when a new task is created, but I can't seem to find a way to do that properly.

My latest attempt looks something like this, but fails to complete any faster multiple requests:

```
namespace Example
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public double Result { get; set; } = 0;
        private List<(Task task, CancellationTokenSource cts)> Tasks = new();
        public async Task UpdateAsync(double value)
        {
            Tasks.ForEach(v => v.cts.Cancel());
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Task task = Task.Run(() => Process(value), tokenSource.Token);
            Tasks.Add((task, tokenSource));
            await Task.WhenAll(Tasks.Select(t => t.task));
        }
        private double Process(double value)
        {
            // Simulate some heavy processing
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

As far as my understanding goes, once a task is started, it can't be cancelled, but all the tasks between the first one (already running) and the last (with the correct result) should be able to be cancelled. How can I achieve that?

**Edit:** Comments and replies so far point towards changing the `Process` function so that it can poll the token. This is unfortunately not an option. You could change the `Process` method with the following, to be closer to my case:

```
[DllImport("bar.dll")]
public static extern double Process(double value);
```

But I want to avoid as much useless work as possible, in order to have the UI as reactive as possible, even if I know it won't be perfect.

Comment: you could iterate and poll against the cancelation token

Comment: Yeah, your task code needs to be interruptible (e.g. poll for cancellation).

Comment: That Process() function in bar.dll does not look like anything that can be easily cancelled.  That's where the buck stops.  You can only get ahead by modifying it, also taking a function pointer.  One it regularly calls to verify if it should stop processing.

Comment: It's technically possible by aborting the thread the task is running on, but that's usually considered bad practice as you're not giving that thread any opportunity to release/clean up resources. You may also leave the API in an undefined state, depending on how it's implemented/consumed. If you're absolutely determined, there's an implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55709530/156755

Comment: Is it an option to run the `Process` method in a [separate process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort/1560567#1560567) than your main executable? Do you have any idea what the `Process` method is actually doing? Is it [CPU-bound or I/O-bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean)?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few different needs here, so I'll try to untangle them and provide solutions.

> rapid changes to the value lead to multiple-seconds lag until the Result value settles on the final result.

I assume you *only* want the final result, and that outdated results are not desired.

> As far as my understanding goes, once a task is started, it can't be cancelled...

Your example code is passing a cancellation token to `Task.Run`. Unfortunately, this only cancels the *scheduling* of the work to the thread pool (which happens immediately), not the *execution* of the work on the thread pool.

> Edit: Comments and replies so far point towards changing the Process function so that it can poll the token. This is unfortunately not an option.

Cancellation is the ideal solution. However, cancellation is *cooperative*, meaning the `Process` function itself must respond to a cancellation request.

If `Process` is actually external and unmodifiable, then the first thing to do is to check for another way to cancel the operation. Sometimes libraries provide a completely separate API for cancellation. One trick that often works with handle-based APIs is to close the handle, which causes all operations on that handle to be cancelled as a side effect.

If none of these are viable, then your only choice is to wrap `Process` into a separate executable, and control it from your main executable. In most cases, this is sufficiently difficult that most people just decide not to do it.

> I have tried to experiment with CancellationToken to cancel the previous task when a new task is created, but I can't seem to find a way to do that properly.

Cancellation is an ideal kind of solution, but if you have the CPU/cores to spare, you could just ignore the previous results and only show the most recently-requested result. This can be as simple as a unique token copied to each invocation and then checked on completion:

```
public class Foo
{
  public double Result { get; set; } = 0;
  private object _currentToken;

  // This code does assume UpdateAsync is called from the UI thread.
  public async Task UpdateAsync(double value)
  {
    _currentToken = new();
    var myToken = _currentToken;
    var myResult = await Task.Run(() => Process(value));
    if (myToken == _currentToken)
      Result = myResult;
  }
}
```

Cancellation is still ideal, since you could stop the CPU usage that will just be wasted producing results that are then thrown away.

> rapid changes to the value lead to multiple-seconds lag until the Result value settles on the final result.

The other way to attack this is the "rapid changes" part. You can debounce your inputs so that there's a lag of, e.g., 200ms before `Process` begins, giving time to cancel the `Process` *before* it starts.

Some combination of debouncing and tokens is usually sufficient for this kind of problem. Although again, the *ideal* solution is to have `Process` support cancellation.

Answer (score 0):

If your long running method `Process(double value)` is a synchronous method written in an external library which you cannot modify then there is nothing you can do - except force killing. But it might create all sorts of other issues - you have no idea how many unsafe handles it opens/closes etc.

However, if you have control over the UI (which seems you do since you can access the user input) then I would strongly suggest you handle it at the UI level in one of the following ways:

1. Show separate queues for every value entered
2. Wait for the input value from the user to stabilize - you seem to be calling the process at `onchange` implying that process is invoked at each keystroke (or spin up/down) - depending on the framework you are using. Instead get the user to commit to the value by providing an "OK" button. (sneaky) If that is not possible, keep an internal timer that waits for the lack of input for some time (say 500ms) before invoking Process.
3. Don't allow the user to enter a new value unless the process is complete.

Answer (score -1):

> As far as my understanding goes, once a task is started, it can't be cancelled

That's not even a tiny bit true.

Specifically what you want to do is pass your `CancellationToken` to your process function, and inside whatever loop you have (or any async-over-sync operations, if any, though that is a gigantic red screaming flag right there) check for `IsCancellationRequested` to bail out early. Something like:

```
double Process(double value, CancellationToken ct)
{
    double result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 50_000_000 && !ct.IsCancellationRequested; ++i)
        // do stuff
    return result;
}
```

You probably don't need to check it every iteration either, every N iterations is fine.

And your other code makes even less sense, by the way. If you want a new task to cancel the others, you should be triggering its cancellation token and await its completion, not keep them all running in that list.

Comment: "As far as my understanding goes, once a task is started, it can't be cancelled" I think what is meant is in the sense that the `Task` mechanisms have no way to cancel the code once started. You need to do it yourself, as shown.

Comment: I'm dealing with an async over sync operation, it may be a red flag, but whatever, I don't have control over the whole stack, the API I need to call is synchronous. In that scenario, triggering the token and awaiting completion won't help, it will go through all the `Process` calls just like in my first scenario.

Comment: "but whatever" -- then that's that. Put that as your comment and move on, I suppose.

Comment: If Process function is written in an external library, then there is really no way to cancel the long running task. Your example assumes that the OP has control over the long running task. If he did, then cancellation was straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

If you're dealing with an external blocking call then you have to throw elegance out the window.

Wrap the blocking operation in a Class that raises an Event with the Result. Keep a reference to that class at Form level so you know if there is an operation currently pending. When you need to "cancel" the current operation you simply unsubscribe from the event on that current instance so you never receive it. Then just orphan it and let it finish it's blocking operation (no one will get its answer/result). Now you can create a new Class and subscribe to its event.

*This assumes that the external blocking call can handle being called multiple times without issue.

Might look something like:

```
public class Foo
{
    public delegate void dlgFooAnswer(double answer);
    public event dlgFooAnswer FooAnswer;

    public async void Process(double value)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
            // Simulate some heavy processing
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            double answer = value * 2;
            FooAnswer?.Invoke(answer);
        });
    }
}
```

Form code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Foo f = null;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (f != null)
        {
            // unsubscribe from event
            f.FooAnswer -= F_FooAnswer;
        }

        label1.Text = "Processing...";
        f = new Foo();
        f.FooAnswer += F_FooAnswer;
        f.Process((double)numericUpDown1.Value);
    }

    private void F_FooAnswer(double answer)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            label1.Text = "Answer: " + answer;
        });
    }

}
```